# Confused with notation regarding integers modulo $3$

Tags: group-theory

$G$ denotes the equivalence classes of integers (mod $3$).

So $G = \{[0], [1], [2]\}.$

I have to show that $(G, +)$ forms a group but my understanding of the notation is holding me back. Here are a few questions I have.

Does $[0] = \{3k\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ ?

If so, wouldn't that mean $G = \bigl\{\{3k\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}, \{3k+1\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}, \{3k+2\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}\bigr\}$, meaning I have $3$ elements which are sets?

If instead, $[0]$ represesented the elements of $\{3k\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ without the braces then I would have $G = \{\ldots-6, 3, 0, 3, 6\ldots, \ldots -5, -2, 1, 4, 7\ldots, \ldots-4, -1, 2, 5, 8\ldots\}$ or in other words $G$ is a set of all integers.

If this second case is true, where $G$ is a set of all integers, then to prove the condition of closure I could say that the sum of any $2$ integers (e.g. $8+2$) is another integer, which is in $G$. That would be that -- no need for any further application of modulo $3$ to my answer before showing the result is in $G$. I understand that this is probably not the case and in fact I do have to include the use of modulo $3$ into the workings of my answer.

Could I get some clarification as to what $[0]$ actually means and what the set $G$ would look like if it was expanded into long form? Finally could the property of closure please be proven the proper way since my method is probably incorrect?

Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Yes and yes to your first two question, **no** to the third one: how could you get for example $\;1\;$ in $\;\{3k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\}\;$ ?!

Comment: Your first attempt is right.  And your description of $G$ as a set of sets hits the nail right on the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first interpretation is correct. $G$ is, in fact, a set of three particular subsets of $\Bbb Z$.

In general, for any $n\in\Bbb Z,$ we have $[n]_3=\{3k+n: k\in\Bbb Z\},$ so that $[m]_3=[n]_3$ if and only if $3\mid(m-n)$. (You should prove this if you haven't already.) The definition of addition is: $$[m]_3+_3[n]_3=[m+n]_3$$ To show that this is a well-defined operation (that closure holds), we must show that if $[m]_3=[m']_3$ and if $[n]_3=[n']_3,$ then $[m]_3+_3[n]_3=[m']_3+_3[n']_3.$ In other words, we must show that if $3\mid(m-m')$ and $3\mid(n-n')$, then $3\mid\bigl((m+n)-(m'+n')\bigr).$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the meaning of $_3[n]_3$ or the equation in general. Is that how the addition of two sets is defined under modulo 3? I've only dealt with addition of elements under introductory group theory but not sets. For elements I would just show that the sum of any two elements in the set results in a term in the set and end my proof of closure at that.

Comment: The notation $[n]_3$ is simply to make clear that we are dealing with equivalence classes of integers modulo $3,$ rather than modulo some other number. The $+_3$ notation is simply to make a distinction between addition in $\Bbb Z$ and addition in $G$, and yes, that is how addition modulo $3$ is defined. Aside from those notational questions, is there anything else about my answer that you're not sure of?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So an example of the application of that equation would be $[1]_3+[2]_3=[3]_3=[0]_3$ and $[0]\in G$ thus proving closure for one combination?

Comment: Yes, indeed $[1]_3+_3[2]_3=[0]_3.$ Still, to actually prove it, you need to prove that the operation is actually well-defined, as I outlined above. If it isn't a well-defined operation, then even individual cases such as this would be nonsense.